# Very slow update with subquery (different tables)

Tags: mysql, update, subquery

I run this query to update "domains" table based on "log" table:

```
UPDATE domains
SET domains.mx_collected = 0
WHERE domains.domain IN
(SELECT log.mail as domain_name FROM log WHERE
`time` >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 30 DAY ) AND
`time` <= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 15 DAY )
group BY domain_name
HAVING count(*) > 200)
```

While the subquery itself runs very fast (0.6 sec) with a result set of only 6 items the update never ends (not after hours). But if I run the update-query with a item list instead of a subquery it successfully ends after 0.02 seconds:

```
UPDATE domains
SET domains.mx_collected = 0
WHERE domains.domain IN 
("0815.ru","123.com","123mail.org","126.com","139.com","13hotmail.com")
```

Question is: why?

Comment: can you show the execution plan?

Comment: MySQL 5.6 optimizes subqueries much better than earlier versions.  I would recommend upgrading.

Comment: Do you have an index on mail?

Answer (score -1):

The subquery will be executed for each row from the outer query, and no index will be used. In addition, 0.6 sec is "relatively" long. For example, if you have 1000 rows in domain table, then expect more them 600 sec (10 minutes).

In the second query, MySQL is able to use the index on 'domain'. This is a feature of using "IN" instead of subquery.

Comment: The sub-query for an `IN` condition does not need to be executed for each row of the outer query. In fact in *can't* be, because it has to be executed *before* the outer query in order to limit that. If MySQL really runs the query for the `IN` condition on each and every row from than the query optimizer is even worse than I thought.

Comment: I think it depends on the version of MySQL. MySQL prior to 5.6 won't run the subquery only once.